# Fetch current module while running cProfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, cprofile

I would like to get ahold of my module (to list all function names), even when using cProfile. How can I do that?

To clarify I'm using some introspection in my own module, but `sys.modules[__main__]` does of course not return my own module any more when running with `-m cProfile`.

To reproduce, create modtest.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Run it like so:

```
$ ./modtest.py
<module '__main__' from './modtest.py'>
$ python -m cProfile ./modtest.py
<module 'cProfile' from '...cProfile.py'>
```

How can I get that last line to say `from './modtest.py'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to grab the module object from `sys.modules` when you provide the module as an argument to `cProfile`. `cProfile` doesn't even import the module for you, it just executes it, you wouldn't even be able to grab it from `sys.modules` after it finished executing.

When run via the `-m` switch, `__main__` will necessarily point to `cProfile`, there's no changing that.

You can always grab the module *name* from `sys.argv[0]`, import it yourself with `importlib` and afterwards list the function names.